# Run shell script after XServer is started?

Tags: linux, qt, shell, startup, boot

How to run shell script when XServer is started and lightdm also. I tried with init.d and rc.local in /etc directory, but my script is calling an gui application so that the reason I need to run it after XServer is started.

I am using Debian Jessie.

Comment: Do you have a .xinitrc in your home directory? Maybe adding a 'exec /path/to/your/script' will do it.

Comment: I have xinitrc file in /etc/X11/xinit directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) .xinitrc in your home directory will be read and executed, otherwise the default `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` is used. So you should be able to create this file and have the shell script started.

Comment: I noticed an interesting thing, tried on RedHat family. The script runs only when first user logs in, it will run if he logs out and log in again. But if a different user logs in, xinitrc will not start. I tried both /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d and adding a line to /etc/X11/xinit/Xsession.