# Raspbian Jessie autostart

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, autostart

I think this question could also be useful for other Raspberry-Pi users who updated from Raspbian Wheezy to Jessie.
My python program with Tkinter GUI starts after a reboot on Wheezy but not on Jessie.
None of the methods described in internet worked for me.
I’ve did following:

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

In the next to last line (before “exit 0”) added following line:

```
/etc/init.d/cron/start
```

This forces crontab to start on reboot.
After that called the crontab window:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Following line added:

```
@reboot /home/pi/starter.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

This should execute a script named starter.sh on reboot and log errors in the cronlog file.
The starter.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python /home/pi/TkinterGUI.py
```

Made this script executable:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/starter.sh
```

Checked the file properties - yes, executable. Executing this script from the command line '/home/pi/starter.sh' makes my TkinterGUI program start. On reboot happens nothing? The cronlog looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File " TkinterGUI.py", line 354, in <module>
root = Tk()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

It is the same display, the only difference is staring manually or autostart on reboot. Asking Google gives no useable answers. I don’t do remote access; my keyboard and monitor are directly connected to the Raspberry.

Comment: Tk expects x11 to be running, since there's no point in a GUI toolkit withouth a window to run in. You could try to fake it by setting the env variable `DISPLAY=:0` in the cron entry.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633594/run-shell-script-after-xserver-is-started

Comment: @Håken Lid: Done, the cronlog gets two identical lines at the beginning:    "No protocol specified"

Comment: Solved! Cron was not the right way. I have generated a new autostart file:    sudo nano /home/pi/.config/autostart/TkinterGIU.desktop

Comment: In this file I wrote this:
[Desktop Entry]                                                                     Type=Application                                                                   Name=TkinterGUI                                                                     Exec=/home/pi/starter.sh                                                      StartupNotify=false                                                                           Thats all! I found this solution here: www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2011021.htm